# Почему сайт отправляется на печать не корректно?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Здрасте!

Вот код:
https://github.com/SeryiBaran/site

Вот сам сайт:
https://seryibaran.github.io/site/

Проблема такая:

Когда нажимаю ПКМ/Печать на своем сайте, печатается только один экран, который в поле зрения, хотя страница очень длинная:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать и что делать?
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: В `devtools` выберите `Render` -> `Media print` и там посмотрите.

Comment: Ничего не изменяется

Answer (score 0):

Все решилось методом тыка. Просто во время верстки сайта я сделал "костыль", и он мешал печатать страницу.

Потом проблема пропала, а сам "костыль" (простите за тавтологию) я убрать забыл.

Это было свойство CSS:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

И оно прятало все что не попадает в экран.

Comment: На скриншоте в вопросе явно видно скролл, так что даже если убирание overflow: hidden и помогло (оно может влиять, например, на размеры флексов), оно всё равно не было изначальной проблемой. Скорее всего надо было искать высоту контейнера, который даёт скролл (или его родителей, возможно даже, html или body)

Comment: скролл дает длинная статья